# Why is my <a download> tag adding .zip to the end of the filename?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I made a React website for something, and one of the buttons downloads a .apk file from my other server, which works fine, except for the fact that it's adding .zip onto the end of the file name. It's downloading fine, it's just that problem thats causing people issues.

Code:

```
<a href="redacted.com/redacted.apk" download><button className="redacted">Android (APK)</button></a>
```

Comment: @Jeppe yes it does, thank you so much!